# Como retornar um array e aparecer apenas o número da contagem

Tags: php

Fiz esse código para que uma contagem do número de comentários fosse realizada, e retornasse o valor de quantos comentários havia na publicação. Porém, ao invés de retornar apenas o valor , está retornando isso:

> `Array ( [COUNT(*)] => 9 )` //Comentários

Como eu faço para que retorne somente o **9** ao invés do `Array` ( `[COUNT(*)] => 9` ) ?

```
<?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comentario");
    $linhas = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
?>

<h4 class="mb-30"><?php print_r ($linhas); ?> Comentários</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar `AS` para tornar o COUNT em um apelido mais fácil e ficaria assim:

```
<?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM comentario");
    $linhas = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
?>

<h4 class="mb-30"><?php echo $linhas['total']; ?> Comentários</h4>
```

Note que você deve mudar urgentemente a API de conexão com mysql de mysql_ para MYSQLI ou PDO, recomendo que leia:

- [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/3635)

Comment: Obrigada!! Funcionou

Comment: @Athena aproveite que esta começando e não use a api antiga do php para mysql, ela foi removida no PHP7 e seus códigos irão falhar nesta versão, troque pelas API mais modernas, como mysqli ou PDO, leia mais em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/3635 --- PS: o banco continua sendo mysql, só a API de comunicação mudou ;)

Answer (score 0):

Eu acredito que você esteja aprendendo a programar com a linguagem [php](/questions/tagged/php), porque essas funções já são depreciadas e ninguém mais utiliza, mas, respondendo basicamente coloque um *alias* (`AS`) na sua [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) e como vai ser retornado um `array` associativo fica fácil trabalhar no seu código de apresentação:

```
<?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM comentario");
    $linhas = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
?>

<h4 class="mb-30"><?php echo $linhas['count']; ?> Comentários</h4>
```

e troque `print_r` para `echo`.

---

Utilize [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php) ou se for o banco de dados `MySQL` o [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.mysqli.php) que são mais atuais e estão sempre sendo atualizados, mas, isso não muda a `SQL` que está na sua pergunta é a mesma coisa. Se quiser aprofundar utilize essa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql) como uma das fontes, no [php.net](https://www.php.net/) que é o site oficial também tem bastante material

Comment: sim estou aprendendo mesmo, muito obrigada, funcionou!